# Continuous SPAM from certain IP/s hosting provider, how to report them if not responding at abuse@company.mail

Tags: spam, spam-filter

last maybe 4 weeks is coming SPAM e-mails from various domains. In common is that when i paste the source code of the e-mail to

https://www.spamcop.net

is detected this provider and their mailbox: abuse@des.capital
i have reported this activity to des capital numerous times via spamcop and also manually to info@des...(got no reply) no effect. I would block the sender, but it is from various domains and various mail content, so i do not know how to block in Thunderbird.

When check "From" in one of the e-mail source and check hostname IP, i see "server9.lindhint.info has address 212.193.29.252"
whois on that IP:

```
inetnum:        212.193.28.0 - 212.193.31.255
netname:        Serveri0n
org:            ORG-DCB8-RIPE
country:        NL
admin-c:        AA35882-RIPE
tech-c:         TA7409-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         RELCOMGROUP-EXT-MNT
created:        2020-12-02T15:36:18Z
last-modified:  2021-05-11T06:56:00Z
source:         RIPE

organisation:   ORG-DCB8-RIPE
org-name:       Des Capital B.V.
country:        NL
org-type:       LIR
address:        Krammer 8
address:        3232HE
address:        Brielle
address:        NETHERLANDS
```

Question: can i contact their IP/network provider or some authority that can force them to cease the SPAM, which, how? RIPE claims "There is nothing we can do if a network operator chooses not to reply." I am not from the country of this host.

Update: it came to my attention that "Serveri0n" (mentioned in "netname" whois) have a colocation customer whose customer is likely the SPAMmer. Serveri0n acted quickly to prevent SPAM. Thank you (answers still welcome)

Comment: There is no authority here, The provider may chose to have their network open to spammers, maybe that's their business model. The only thing you can do is block that IP on your mailserver, so contact your mail provider if you are not hosting your own server.

Comment: You may try to postmaster@domain if abuse@domain don't answer.